# How to get longest path instead of shortes path in geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Any idea how to resolve this topic longest path instead shortest?

[image]

Comment: I suspect the answer to this is [you can't](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem), unless you can constrain the problem further.

Comment: Yes I know stupid question It 'd go to the infinity. What I meant is to take longest path from 0 to height of Z axis.

Comment: Without loops this problem is not trivial to solve I'm afraid